# Smaller function not returning any values

Tags: c++

I have written a bubble sort program that works but I need to have a smaller sub-function that it calls in order to switch the elements. My bubble sort looks like this:

```
for(int i = N-1; i>0; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(arr[j]<arr[j+1])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

and my current sub-function looks like this:

```
 void swap2(int x,int x1)
{
    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = x1;
    x1 = temp;    
}
```

When I have it within my code, it doesn't work, what would I have to do in order to make the swap2 function actually swap my elements?

Comment: Where is your `return` statement respectively your passed by reference parameters?

Comment: `void swap2(int x,int x1)` accomplishes nothing since you pass your arguments by value (meaning copies). I expect in release mode a smart compiler will not even call swap2().

Comment: Just use `std::swap`...

Comment: What do you think `swap(1,2);` will do? Make all the 1's in your code act like 2's and all the 2's act like 1's?

Answer (score 0):

Change `void swap2(int x,int x1)` to `void swap2(int &x,int &x1)` if you want to see the result outside the function. That way you'll be passing arguments by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference parameters like this:

```
void swap2(int & x, int & x1)
```

...to have your swap function *modify* the values that get passed in. (You might hear these referred to as "in-out parameters"—parameters that get both read from and written to by the function.

This is equivalent (albeit with arguably cleaner syntax) to passing in pointers to the values you want to modify, like this:

```
void swap2(int * x, int * x1)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *x1;
    *x1 = temp;  
}
```